# UIScrollView Delegate as a protocol default implementation

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, swift-protocols

I am trying to implement default implementation for `UIScrollViewDelegate` method:

`func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>)`

using a `protocol`.

If I put this method inside the class, it's called; however, if I try to use as the default implementation via `protocol`, it's never called.

Code:

```
protocol DefaultScrollViewEndDragging {
    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>)
}

extension DefaultScrollViewEndDragging {
    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        print("scrollViewWillEndDragging is called")
        // THIS IS NEVER CALLED
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, DefaultScrollViewEndDragging {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        print("Cell \(indexPath.row)")
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .orange
        return cell
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think you looking for something like this

```
protocol DefaultScrollViewEndDragging : UIScrollViewDelegate {
    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>)
}

extension DefaultScrollViewEndDragging {
    func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
        print("scrollViewWillEndDragging is called")
        // THIS IS NEVER CALLED
    }
}
```

**Unfortunately, protocol extensions are not accessible by Obj-C. so it's not getting called** `scrollViewWillEndDragging`

*From note*

> Again, the sole exception to this is protocol extensions. Unlike any
>   other construct in the language, protocol extension methods are
>   dispatched statically in a situation where a virtual dispatch would
>   cause different results. No compiler error prevents this mismatch.
>   https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20151207/001707.html

Comment: @user1107173 Unfortunately, protocol extensions are not accessible by Obj-C. so it's not getting called `scrollViewWillEndDragging`

Comment: @user1107173 please check my updated answer. if you have still confusion any part then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**Correct Code**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView!.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    print("Cell \(indexPath.row)")
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .orange
    return cell
}
//MARK: scrollview Delegate Method
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    print("scrollViewWillEndDragging is called")
}
```

}

Comment: I mentioned in my question that it works this way.  I am trying to use it as a default implementation.

Comment: what you want to do? it's not going to work the way you want. you have to trigger protocol method by using delegate.method() to somewhere and then it will automatically call where you implement this method. please edit your questing in detail what you want to achieve.